# In C++, how can I create a `std::initializer_list<base *>` without new and without declaring individual elements separately?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, initialization, initializer-list

In C++, you can declare an array of something at the file scope:

```
static foo a[] = { foo(), foo(), foo() };
```

The individual foo objects have static storage (i.e. they are not allocated at run-time).

If I had a base class inherited by two or more derived classes, the following would compile but not work as expected due to slicing:

```
static base a[] = { derived1(), derived2() };
```

Something like this should not cause slicing to happen:

```
static derived1 d1;
static derived2 d2;
static base *a[] = { &d1, &d2 };
```

My question is: How can I do the same without having to declare `d1` and `d2` separately from `a`, and while keeping static storage for the individual (pointed-to) elements? The following gives a "taking address of temporary" error:

```
static base *a[] = { &derived1(), &derived2() };
```

Maybe it would be possible to define a `constexpr` variadic template function? Something like:

```
template<typename... Args>
constexpr std::initializer_list<base *> base_array(Args... args) {
    ...
}
```

Then I could write:

```
static base *a[] = base_ptr_array(derived1(), derived2());
```

Maybe this would have the same "taking address of temporary" problem, though my idea was that since this is a constexpr it would work similarly to `{ foo(), foo(), foo() }` above (which *doesn't* create temporaries).

Comment: You want a hack to discard the type information you have? Why? Just name those objects, define an array of pointers if you need to iterate over them, just say yes to both.

Comment: Technically you can do almost anything with a variadic macro. If you absolutely want. For inspiration (how to write needlessly inpenetrable brittle code that maybe looks nice) look at the Boost parameters sub-library.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Naming them is less ergonomic if I would like to have potentially hundreds of elements, since it means maintaining two lists instead of one. Imagine if you had to name every element of regular (non-pointer) array initializers, it wouldn't be very nice, right?

Comment: For maintainability of hundreds or thousands of objects, use a macro scheme. A simple one is to `#include` the same initializer data file with different definitions of a macro, to generate respectively named objects and pointer array. Oh, I should mention: when you need this, it's almost 100% sure that you're on the wrong road...

Answer (score 7):

You can use some template to avoid declaring those static variables:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template<class Base, class... Ts>
struct foo {
    foo()
        : foo(Ts{}..., std::index_sequence_for<Ts...>{})
    {}
    std::tuple<Ts...> deriveds;
    std::array<Base*, sizeof...(Ts)> arr;

private:
    template<std::size_t... Is>
    foo(Ts... ts, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
        : deriveds(ts...)
        , arr{ &std::get<Is>(deriveds)...}
    {}
};


// test 
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    virtual void show() const {
        std::cout << "A\n";
    }
    virtual ~A() = default;
};
struct B: public A
{
    void show() const override {
        std::cout << "B\n";
    }
};
struct C: public A
{
    void show() const override {
        std::cout << "C\n";
    }
}; 

foo<A, A, B, C> f;

int main() {
    for ( A *ptr : f.arr ) {
        ptr->show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Definite up-vote for ingenuity. But do you really need the extra `std::array`? You can save a bit on the static storage by defining iterators for `foo` that return a `Base` pointer.

Comment: Oh, never mind. Traversing the tuple with an iterator would be nightmarish to write.

Comment: You define some complex machinery for default-initializing the objects.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Since the addresses of those objects should stored in the array, I don't know how to simplify further. If you have any idea please tell me.

Comment: `std::tuple<Ts...> deriveds{};`. You still need machinery for initializing the array, but it's a reduction. In the other direction, consider that default-initialized (or really value-initialized) objects are not that useful.

Answer (score 6):

To be honest, I think you are trying to use the wrong tool for the job. Here's how I see it:

1. You want polymorphic behavior from the array elements.
2. You have a finite set of classes you care about. If it was open, you wouldn't be able to write an initializer for an array.

This reads "closed set" polymorphism to me. And you can accomplish it without dynamic allocation in [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17). You don't even need the classes to have a common base class. Only to have the same members you wish to call. All it takes is a [`std::variant`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) of types, and an array of variants:

```
using variant_type = std::variant<derived1, derived2, ..., derived_n>;

static variant_type a[] = {
  derived1(), derived2(), ..., derived_n()
};
```

And there you have it. You get your polymorphic behavior, just need to [`std::visit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) an array element instead of calling a member function via pointer:

```
for(auto& v : a)
  std::visit([](auto& e) {
    // Do something with e
    // It's a reference to one of the types the variant can hold
  }, v);
```

Comment: I am not sure if the "finite set of classes" point holds. Let's say I have a library function that takes an array of base pointers. The user of the library should be able to define their own derived class and then define a (still static!) array of elements including (pointers to) objects of the derived type and pass it to the library.

Comment: @Vegard - The array has a fixed size. You provide a fixed initializer. It's not open ended.

Comment: The array has a fixed size, but the number of derived classes is not fixed from the library's point of view.

Comment: @Vegard - It becomes fixed when you write an initializer that contains them. I'm starting to think you presented the [Y to your X in your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I appreciate your answer (and I've upvoted it), and yes -- I tried to abstract my question from the actual practical problem that prompted the question. That doesn't mean I wouldn't like an answer to the specific question I asked, even if that answer is "that's not possible". You are the one who rephrased my question and then answered that rephrased question. My previous comments on this answer are a clarification of why your answer does not solve my practical problem, not an objection to your proposed solution of your rephrased question.

Comment: @Vegard - I didn't rephrase it as much as you think. I summarized what I gathered from your post and what I know of C++ and its constraints. If this distillation ends up solving another problem, then you abstracted too much away.