# Static initialisation of list of objects as baseclass pointers

Tags: c++, initialization, polymorphism

I want to create at static list of objects, where the list contains pointers or references to the baseclass. This list will be a constant static at namespace scope.

The list may be a std::vector, std::array a raw array. The list is intended as a kind of lookup table from which I have to create multiple. Therefore I am looking for simple and readable initialization.

I know we can do:

```
static MyObject Foo(1);
static MyObject* pFoo(&foo);
```

Creating an array of this is not directly possible, what I in essence like to do is:

```
static std::vector<MyObject*> objects = { &MyObject(1), &MyObject(2) }
```

Or even better use a smart pointer. This is however not possible since MyObject is a temporary and using static within the initializer list of objects is not allowed.

Is there any other way to directly create a static list with pointers or references to a baseclass ?

C++14 or C++17 is not an option.

Comment: `static` has many different meanings in different contexts in C++. You need to take a step back and start explaining from the start. Also, make sure you're not asking a so-called "XY question'.

Comment: See my old answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48851186/in-c-how-can-i-create-a-stdinitializer-listbase-without-new-and-witho/48851432#48851432

Comment: It is a nice option and basically what I am looking for. Unfortunately I am not able to use C++14 or C++17.